# How to select latest record of particular details

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in SQL server table like below,

I have data like below,

```
id  Cust_id   Name  Qty    Trans_date
_______________________________________

1   101     Srini   10    01-May-2018
2   101     Srini   20    01-May-2018
3   102     Arun    100   01-May-2018
4   102     Arun    200   01-May-2018
5   101     Srini   10    02-May-2018
6   101     Srini   30    02-May-2018
```

---

I want resultsets below,

```
5   101     Srini   10    02-May-2018
6   101     Srini   30    02-May-2018
3   102     Arun    100   01-May-2018
4   102     Arun    200   01-May-2018
```

I need query to get the latest trans date details. Srini's latest record is on 02nd May and Arun's latest is 01st May.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be handled well by the difference in row number method.  This method is fairly robust, and can tolerate a situation where separate islands of customer records all have the same date.  To see why this works, explore the demo; it is not easy to explain in words.

```
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) -
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_id ORDER BY id) diff
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_id ORDER BY diff DESC) rank
    FROM cte1
)

SELECT id, Cust_id, Name, Qty, Trans_date
FROM cte2
WHERE rank = 1;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

[DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
select * 
from ( select * 
            , DENSE_RANK() over (partition by custid order by Trans_date desc) rn
         from table
     ) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: @cybemoney Just why did you roll back my edit to my question.  Please don't edit this answer.

Comment: I rolled it back because the edit message was "Added Dense Rank link", however no such link was added so the edit lied about its actual intent. Suggested edits should be *clear* as to what improvements are made, the original suggested edit should not have been approved and was rejected by every reviewer that reviewed it before you approved it (which was binding as you are the author). Please justify the edit. I see that it added `from table`- in review this comes under "attempt to reply" as this modifies your code without any justification given.

Comment: Saying that, I'm not even sure *how* you approved the edit as two rejects usually rejects the entire edit, however you were able to approve the suggested edit after the two rejects were made.

Comment: @cybermonkey I did NOT approve the edit.  I don't need to justify an edit to my post.

Comment: The [suggested edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19786593) says differently- that edit should *not* have been approved (and the other reviewer came to the same conclusion, before you approved it), which is why I rolled your post back in the first place. All I'm asking what improvement does adding `from table` make? Is it a code fix? Is it for compatibility? Explaining the improvement to me makes me a better reviewer as it allows me to better judge a suggested edit where the editor has not adequately justified their edit.

Comment: @cybermonkey When the editor is the OP leave it alone

Comment: Yes, but the editor was *not* you in this case. Later I’m going to take this to Meta as you really are not being helpful in this matter. I’m simply trying to understand what improvements the edit from the other user (not you) made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171616/discussion-between-cybermonkey-and-paparazzo).

Answer (score 0):

[DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) Function should worrk

```
Select * from ( select * 
        , DENSE_RANK() over (partition by cust_id order by Trans_date DESC) row_n from table_name
 ) A
Where A.row_n = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE 
WHERE  TRANS_DATE = (SELECT Max(TRANS_DATE) 
                     FROM   TABLE) 
       AND NAME = "YOURCHOICE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE(id,  Cust_id ,  Name  ,Qty,    Trans_date)
AS
(
SELECT 1,101,'Srini', 10 ,'01-May-2018' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,101,'Srini', 20 ,'01-May-2018' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,102,'Arun' , 100,'01-May-2018' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,102,'Arun' , 200,'01-May-2018' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,101,'Srini', 10 ,'02-May-2018' UNION ALL
SELECT 6,101,'Srini', 30 ,'02-May-2018' 
)
SELECT ID, 
       CUST_ID, 
       NAME, 
       QTY, 
       TRANS_DATE 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               ROW_NUMBER() 
                 OVER( 
                   PARTITION BY CUST_ID 
                   ORDER BY TRANS_DATE DESC) AS Rnk 
        FROM   CTE)Dt 
WHERE  Dt.RNK <= 2
```

Result

```
ID  CUST_ID NAME    QTY  TRANS_DATE
------------------------------------
6   101 Srini       30   02-May-2018
5   101 Srini       10   02-May-2018
4   102 Arun        200  01-May-2018
3   102 Arun        100  01-May-2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution not using Ranking functions.

this gives a different execution plan to other solutions and may perform better in your environment.

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP(id INT, 
                 Cust_id SMALLINT,  
                 Name  VARCHAR(50) ,
                 Qty SMALLINT,    
                 Trans_date DATE)

INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES 
( 1,101,'Srini', 10 ,'01-May-2018' ),
( 2,101,'Srini', 20 ,'01-May-2018' ),
( 3,102,'Arun' , 100,'01-May-2018' ),
( 4,102,'Arun' , 200,'01-May-2018' ),
( 5,101,'Srini', 10 ,'02-May-2018' ),
( 6,101,'Srini', 30 ,'02-May-2018' )


;WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    Cust_id,MAX(Trans_Date) MaxTrans
FROM    
    #TMP
GROUP BY Cust_id
)
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    #TMP T
        INNER JOIN cte C
            ON
            T.Cust_id = C.Cust_id
            AND
            T.Trans_date = C.MaxTrans
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where Trans_date = (select max(Trans_date) 
                    from table t1
                    where t1.cust_id = t.cust_id
                   );
```